# Pubsub messages are getting dropped before reaching to our internal microservices

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, netty, google-cloud-pubsub, reactor-netty

We are using google cloud pub sub pull mechanism, from past couple of days we are seeing the below error in our service logs-

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Abrupt GOAWAY closed sent stream. HTTP/2 error code: ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM (Bandwidth exhausted), debug data: too_many_rst_streams
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResourceExhaustedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Abrupt GOAWAY closed sent stream. HTTP/2 error code: ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM (Bandwidth exhausted), debug data: too_many_rst_streams
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:67)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1132)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1270)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1038)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:808)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:535)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
...
```

**using below google cloud versions -**

```
<spring-cloud-gcp.version>3.6.3</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
spring boot version - 2.6.8
netty version - 4.1.82.Final
grpc version - 1.45.1
Java version - 11
```

i have tried to update the netty and grpc version, but it did not helped, messages are still getting dropped before reaching to service and getting the same error as above (description section).

Comment: `too_many_rst_streams` is the important thing there, which is coming from the server. I've not seen that one before, but it sounds like it might be triggered by the number of RPC cancellations. It is probably best to open a support case.